# Bayesian estimation of case fatality rate?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, epidemiology

Let's say we're tracking a global epidemic, such as COVID-19, and we want to estimate the case fatality rate (CFR). The formula for CFR is just `100 * [n(deaths)/n(confirmed cases)]`, so the simplest way to get a current estimate of CFR is just to do that computation with the latest available global data. As of yesterday, that's `100 * (1770/71226)`, or about 2.5%.

Is there a Bayesian approach to deriving that estimate that would allow me to account for observed variation in the CFR across spatial units? Using yesterday's data, we see quite a bit of variability in the observed rate across provinces/states, the lowest level of observation in [the data I'm using](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series):

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.9868  0.6591 33.3333
```

This variability isn't just random noise, as it also stems, in part, from meaningful differences in things like healthcare capacity, response strategies, the politics of reporting these cases, and so on. So what I'd like is to find a way to derive an estimate that accounts for those aspects.

The approach that came to mind was to fit a mixed-effects model to the data with the observed rates as the dependent variable, a fixed intercept, and then random intercepts for spatial units (e.g., countries) within which these rates are observed. In R, I would do that with:

```
lme4::lmer(cfr ~ 1 + (1 | Country.Region), data = df)
```

When I ran that line on the latest data from 54 provinces/states (the unit of observation) nested in 30 countries, here's what I got. Note that the estimated fixed intercept does differ from the global stat, which was about 2.5%.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: cfr ~ 1 + (1 | Country.Region)
   Data: .

REML criterion at convergence: 298.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.06936 -0.03151 -0.03151 -0.00290  2.97269 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Country.Region (Intercept) 38.2494  6.1846  
 Residual                    0.5201  0.7212  
Number of obs: 75, groups:  Country.Region, 30

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    1.694      1.136   1.491
```

Is there a better way to do this? What am I missing?

And, if this approach (or one like it) is reasonable, how can I account for the fact that the quantity of interest is bounded at 0 and 100 when I run simulations from the model to generate a distribution of plausible CFRs? I'm guessing I need to use a different family of model in the first place, but which would be most appropriate for a dependent variable that's a rate?

For the intrepid, here's a `dput` of the data I'm using when I run that call to `lmer`. It's a table with 75 rows representing 75 states or provinces (`Province.State`) nested in 30 countries (`Country.Region`). The rate of interest is `cfr`, which was computed from `n_deaths` and `n_confirmed`.

```
structure(list(Country.Region = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Belgium", "Cambodia", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Egypt", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Hong Kong", "India", 
"Italy", "Japan", "Macau", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", 
"Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", 
"Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", 
"Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", 
"Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", 
"Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", 
"Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", 
"Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", "Mainland China", 
"Mainland China", "Malaysia", "Nepal", "Others", "Philippines", 
"Russia", "Singapore", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sweden", 
"Taiwan", "Thailand", "UK", "United Arab Emirates", "US", "US", 
"US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "Vietnam"
), Province.State = c("New South Wales", "Queensland", "South Australia", 
"Victoria", "", "", "British Columbia", "London, ON", "Toronto, ON", 
"", "", "", "", "Hong Kong", "", "", "", "Macau", "Anhui", "Beijing", 
"Chongqing", "Fujian", "Gansu", "Guangdong", "Guangxi", "Guizhou", 
"Hainan", "Hebei", "Heilongjiang", "Henan", "Hubei", "Hunan", 
"Inner Mongolia", "Jiangsu", "Jiangxi", "Jilin", "Liaoning", 
"Ningxia", "Qinghai", "Shaanxi", "Shandong", "Shanghai", "Shanxi", 
"Sichuan", "Tianjin", "Tibet", "Xinjiang", "Yunnan", "Zhejiang", 
"", "", "Diamond Princess cruise ship", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "Taiwan", "", "", "", "Boston, MA", "Chicago, IL", "Los Angeles, CA", 
"Madison, WI", "Orange, CA", "San Antonio, TX", "San Benito, CA", 
"San Diego County, CA", "Santa Clara, CA", "Seattle, WA", "Tempe, AZ", 
""), Lat = c(-33.8688, -27.4698, -34.9285, -37.8136, 50.5039, 
12.5657, 49.2827, 42.9849, 43.6532, 26.8206, 61.9241, 46.2276, 
51.1657, 22.3193, 20.5937, 41.8719, 35.6762, 22.1987, 31.82571, 
40.18238, 30.05718, 26.07783, 36.0611, 23.33841, 23.82908, 26.81536, 
19.19673, 38.0428, 47.862, 33.88202, 30.97564, 27.61041, 44.09448, 
32.97027, 27.61401, 43.66657, 41.29284, 37.26923, 35.65945, 35.19165, 
36.34377, 31.20327, 37.57769, 30.61714, 39.29362, 30.1534, 41.11981, 
24.97411, 29.18251, 4.2105, 28.3949, 35.4437, 12.8797, 61.524, 
1.3521, 37.5665, 40.4637, 7.8731, 60.1282, 23.6978, 13.7563, 
55.3781, 23.4241, 42.3601, 40.6331, 34.0522, 43.0731, 33.7879, 
29.4241, 36.5761, 32.7157, 37.3541, 47.7511, 34.0489, 21.0278
), Long = c(151.2093, 153.0251, 138.6007, 144.9631, 4.4699, 104.991, 
-123.121, -81.2453, -79.3832, 30.8025, 25.7482, 2.2137, 10.4515, 
114.1694, 78.9629, 12.5674, 139.6503, 113.5439, 117.2264, 116.4142, 
107.874, 117.9895, 103.8343, 113.422, 108.7881, 106.8748, 109.7455, 
114.5149, 127.7622, 113.614, 112.2707, 111.7088, 113.9456, 119.464, 
115.7221, 126.1917, 122.6086, 106.1655, 96.02564, 108.8701, 118.1529, 
121.4554, 112.2922, 102.7103, 117.333, 88.7879, 85.17822, 101.4868, 
120.0985, 101.9758, 84.124, 129.638, 121.774, 105.3188, 103.8198, 
126.978, -3.7492, 80.7718, 18.6435, 120.9605, 100.5018, -3.436, 
53.8478, -71.0589, -89.3985, -118.2437, -89.4012, -117.8531, 
-98.4936, -120.9876, -117.1611, -121.9552, -120.74, -111.094, 
105.8342), date = structure(c(18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 
18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 
18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 
18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 
18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 
18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 
18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 
18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 
18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308, 18308), class = "Date"), 
    n_confirmed = c(4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    12L, 16L, 57L, 3L, 3L, 59L, 10L, 962L, 380L, 551L, 287L, 
    90L, 1316L, 237L, 144L, 162L, 300L, 445L, 1231L, 58182L, 
    1004L, 70L, 617L, 925L, 89L, 121L, 70L, 18L, 236L, 537L, 
    328L, 129L, 481L, 124L, 1L, 71L, 171L, 1167L, 22L, 1L, 355L, 
    3L, 2L, 75L, 29L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 34L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 16L), n_deaths = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 11L, 13L, 1696L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    n_recovered = c(4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 
    3, 0, 12, 5, 255, 108, 207, 82, 54, 465, 49, 46, 52, 105, 
    79, 440, 6639, 464, 8, 218, 240, 30, 40, 33, 13, 71, 173, 
    140, 50, 131, 45, 1, 12, 42, 456, 7, 1, 0, 1, 2, 18, 9, 2, 
    1, 0, 2, 14, 8, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7), cfr = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.33333333333333, 0, 1.75438596491228, 
    0, 0, 1.69491525423729, 0, 0.623700623700624, 1.05263157894737, 
    0.907441016333938, 0, 2.22222222222222, 0.151975683890578, 
    0.843881856540084, 0.694444444444444, 2.46913580246914, 1, 
    2.47191011235955, 1.05605199025183, 2.91499089065347, 0.298804780876494, 
    0, 0, 0.108108108108108, 1.12359550561798, 0.826446280991736, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.37243947858473, 0.304878048780488, 0, 0.623700623700624, 
    2.41935483870968, 0, 1.40845070422535, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33.3333333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -75L))
```

PS. On GitHub, I have since found a great worked example of a non-Bayesian approach to this problem; see [here](https://github.com/calthaus/ncov-cfr). I guess this is how the epidemiology pros tackle the problem in real time...

Comment: A couple of things: 1) you might consider a beta regression model in which you do not multiply the fraction by 100, and 2) any chance you can post the dataset you are using? We could try to reconstruct your dataset based on the links, but it would be good to have what you are working with.

Comment: @ErikRuzek, thanks for taking a look. I just added a `dput` of the data to the question.

Comment: Been playing around with the data and it's not a straightforward analysis. It may require a purpose-built Bayesian model. I've looked at beta mixed models (Frequentist and Bayesian varieties), modeled `n_deaths` using Poission and Negative Binomial (again using both Frequentist and Bayesian approaches), as well as the zero-inflated version of all of these. By model fit (AIC, WAIC), the zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model seems to fit the data best, however, it still is not recovering all the 0s in the data.

Comment: Thanks, @ErikRuzek. At the very least, it's reassuring to hear I wasn't just overlooking something obvious. I've also ended up tinkering with beta (frequentist) and Poisson (mixed effects with `n_deaths` as target and offset for `n_confirmed`). It looks like the main stumbling blocks are the small `n` and, as you note, the large share of 0s (good for humans, bad for estimation).